# Data entity inventory system - how can an "item" have an undefined-entity "owner"?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, database-design, entity

**Context**

Specifically, I am using Core Data to manage a new object graph, translating from a No-sql type persistent data store.

In an object-oriented design, a class/object may implement any number of interfaces or protocols.

**My entities**

Simplified, the first three entities look like this:

```
store
items - array

person
items - array

cart (or suitcase, etc)
items - array
```

Every mobile person has (at least) two inventory containers: their own self (such as their clothing, or things in pockets), and the container/cart/suitcase they're bringing.  Technically, this system also supports a person traveling with multiple containers, but at least one, and thus at least two general inventory containers.

In the old messy No-sql persistent storage, there was no data normalization and every item was having its name and item-specific data duplicated across every owned instance.

Now, I am planning to have another two entities:

```
item
name - string
itemcode - string

itemheld
itemcode - relationship (string/foreign key)
owner -  CANNOT FIGURE THIS OUT
quantity - number
```

The many-to-many relationship "itemheld" has specific properties per-instance, including quantity.

**Ideal solution, that I can't determine how to implement**

If possible, I would like to avoid using an abstract entity "itemholder" or "owner" above person, store, cart, and leave the parent entity for more store/person/container-specific parent code, and I'd rather use something like an interface or protocol for an itemholder.

Is this possible?  Or must I use an abstract parent entity?

Is there a better way?

**An idea for a solution:**

Note- I've been thinking about this for a couple days, and planning and replanning the structure, and I think I just came up an option: an "itemholder" concrete entity that has one-to-one relationships to any possible holder type, but seems terrible at first (includes updated itemheld):

```
itemholder
ownerperson - object or null
ownercontainer - object or null
ownerstore - objector null

itemheld
itemcode - relationship (string/foreign key)
owner -  itemholder
quantity - number
```

Would that be the best solution?

Comment: You either need a superclass 'holder' above person/store/cart so that your `itemheld` `owner` can be a relationship or you need to create 3 different types of `itemheld` each with a different `owner` relationship.

Comment: @Paulw11  Those are both good ideas. Further thinking has lead me to accept and prefer the former of your two suggestions. It does make sense to use a holder as a superclass, and that holder superclass above any more-abstract person/store/cart base classes too. Earlier, I felt using two levels of abstract base classes was overkill, but not now. Cool.